# Naming Divs and Skeleton CSS

Tags: css, html

I've been following a YouTube tutorial on How to create a WP theme. I don't understand how the naming of div class works in this case.

```
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <div class="five columns clearfix">
                <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/templogo.png" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>"></a>
            </div><!--#five columns clearfix-->

            <div class="sixteen columns nav-bar">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'main-nav', 'container' => 'nav')); ?>
            </div><!--#sixteen columns nav-bar-->                   
        </header>
    </div><!--#container-->
```

I can only guess that the "n columns" before the real nav class was for the skeleton.css we used. So to continue to my question, when we started doing CSS, we edited the "sixteen columns nav-bar" in the CSS as ".nav-bar" only, why is that? I was expecting we'll use ".sixteen columns nav-bar" since it was the div class.

Once again, I would appreciate any help and some explanation. Thank's in advance Community!

Answer (score 0):

This CSS assignment: `<div class="sixteen columns nav-bar">` means the div has 3 classes: `.sixteen`, `.columns`, and `.nav-bar`.

You want to reference `.sixteen.columns.nav-bar` in your css if you are overriding.

If you reference it as this `.sixteen columns nav-bar`, the CSS parser would look for a DOM node with the class `.sixteen` which contains a tag called `columns` which contains yet another tag called `nav-bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You should always try and leave your base styles alone.  sixteen and columns are core styles for how you grid should work.  Do you best not to overrides those styles.

If you need to add styling to the nav-bar, i would continue to use the

.nav-bar
or
div.nav-bar

I would also recommend not changing the sizing when you add styles to nav-bar.  Again, you want to leave the grid to do what its was meant to do.  I would suggest only adding styling, like background, color, etc, but stay away from width